Makefile: creating a function results in an error
My program recieves command line arguments.
I want my Makefile to be capable of processing the arguments like:
make run arg1 arg2 arg3

or
make debug arg1 arg2 arg3

In my Makefile, I use the approach suggested in this answer.
The first version was
# Description of variables

# If the first argument is "run" or "debug"...
ifeq (run,$(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)))
        # use the rest as arguments for "run"
        ARGS := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS))
        # ...and turn them into do-nothing targets
        $(eval $(ARGS):;@:)
else ifeq (debug,$(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)))
        # use the rest as arguments for "run"
        ARGS := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS))
        # ...and turn them into do-nothing targets
        $(eval $(ARGS):;@:)
endif

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

# The rest of the Makefile

and it worked fine.
To eliminate code duplication, I decided to describe the function parse_args:
# Description of variables

# Function to parse command line arguments
define parse_args
        # Extract the rest of the arguments after the first one
        $(eval ARGS := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
        # ...and turn them into do-nothing targets
        $(eval $(ARGS):;@:)
endef

# If the first argument is "run" or "debug"...
ifeq (run,$(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)))
        $(call parse_args)
else ifeq (debug,$(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)))
        $(call parse_args)
endif

# The rest of the Makefile

But this version of code produces an error:
:~/c/database_binary_and_hash_search$ make debug file add apple
Makefile:109: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.

Maybe someone can explain why the code behaves like this?

Does this answer your question? Passing arguments to "make run"

"I want my Makefile to be capable of processing the arguments like [...]" -- then you want to write a shell script, not a makefile.  Possibly you could structure it as a front end for make, supported by a separate makefile, but it's not clear whether even that much make would be worthwhile to you.

You should just look at the GNU Make manual Appendix B which explains exactly what each error means and why you would see it: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html

Using $(call ...) here is useless.  You are not actually passing any values as arguments to the macro so $(call parse_args) is 100% identical to just using $(parse_args).

@MadScientist It means that there is a line which starts with a space, tab, or some other whitespace without having a target in front of it.
If I remove the indentation inside the parse_args macro the error presists. If I remove the identation before macro calls in the condition I get the missing separator error. If I create a target before defining the macro, that doesn't help either.
So the knowledge about the error doesn't help me much :(

@HardcoreHenry Yes, the method I use is the second upvoted in this very topic :)

You're trying to use make in a manner it wasn't intended to be used.  As such you're opening yourself up to many sharp sticks.  Any arguments without an = or leading - should be considered a target.  I would highly recommend against using the approach you are mentioning.   A better mechanism of passing in arguments is to use argument variables on the command line as so:
   make run RUN_ARGS="arg1 arg2 arg3"

and then parse the RUN_ARGS in the makefile (this is assuming none of your arguments can have spaces in them.  If they can have spaces, you can do:
   make run RUN_ARG1=arg1 RUN_ARG2=arg2 RUN_ARG3="arg3 with space"

but this makes parsing a bit more complicated, as now you have to go through $(.VARIABLES) and look for anything that starts with RUN_ARGS... ).
Finally, if you're looking to do this because you want a more concise command line, then the way to do this is to write a wrapper script that takes the arguments in the format you want, and then calls make, and passes the arguments to make in the format I mentioned above.

"you're opening yourself up to many sharp sticks"
As well as I aware of it can be: 1) if there is a "test: foo" target already, "make run pip install test" will still run the "foo" target (but the solution is to replace the 'eval' line by $(eval $(RUN_ARGS):dummy;@:); 2) The method I use won't handle args with spaces, but yours also has some issues with that; 3) It's not possible to pass anything in quotes like "foo", but I'm not going to do it in my relatively small demo program; Maybe I missed some possible serious issues?

Consider if one of your arguments happens to be clean, and you have a clean target...   You may be able to get this to work on a very small setup, if you constrain the user not to use certain argument names, etc, but it will not scale in the long run, and it is not good practice.   I would recommend using a wrapper script if you want to pass arguments directly.
